# remap Caps Lock on OSX 10.6.8

Tags: macos, keyboard

I have for a long time used [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/changelog.html) in Snow Leopard. I have always stayed on top of OS update. Today, suddenly my CapsLock no longer was remapped to Control, but it was just a regular CapsLock. So I went into the settings for [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/changelog.html) and noticed that CapsLock could no longer be set. Instead it gave a link to [PCKeyboardHack](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/changelog.html#t0p4). So I downloaded that and tried to use it. But when I try to select the Control key to remap to, it just becomes some kind erratic delete key or something. Definitely not a Control key.

Comment: I thought PCKeyboardHack was for PC keyboards. So did you update KeyRemap and then it stopped working?

Comment: @slhck, weird thing, I didn't do anything. KeyRemap maybe can autoupdate?

Comment: Not that I know of, or at least not without your consent, as I think it requires admin privileges and you'd have to enter your password. Can you maybe try to reinstall KeyRemap?

Comment: @slhck, tried that a few times. KeyRemap actually says in the CapsLock line that you should instead use PCKeyboardHack for CapsLock support. I am trying older versions of KeyRemap now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading comprehension is important... my defense, it DID WORK for many months without PCKeyboardHack, how I don't know. Maybe I upgraded KeyRemap4MacBook and then did not reboot until now.

Anyway, the solution is to use [PCKeyboardHack](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/changelog.html#t0p4) and then to actually [follow the instructions](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/extra.html#t1p1). In particular step 3,``open "System Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys..." and change CapsLock configuration to "No Action":´´
[image]

Comment: And now that setting reverted again. Strange, I had to go in and do the No Action setting once more.

Comment: And again. It's when I type some weird combo it happens...